# Spring @RequestMapping "Not Contains" Regex

Tags: java, regex, spring, request-mapping

I have this RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/route/to-{destination}-from-{departure}.html", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
```

And I would like to add that RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/route/to-{destination}.html", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
```

So it can serve all the "without departure" routes. That, however, creates a conflict as a "/route/to-destination-from-departure" url actually match this second RequestMapping as well...
Fair enough so my solution was to specify a regex:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/route/to-{destination:^((?!-from-).)+}.html", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
```

So that RequestMapping will not match if "destination" contains "-from-".

And... it does not work! The url "/route/to-barcelona-from-paris.html" is succesfully served by the first RequestMapping but the url "/route/to-barcelona.html" is not served at all... What I am missing?

Notes: I would like not to use a java solution such as having a single "/route/to-{destination}" RequestMapping then checking if "destination" contains "-from-".. :) Also, I can't alter those routes because of SEO...

Comment: Try `{destination:(?!.*-from-).+}.html` or `{destination:(?!.*-from-)[^\/]+}.html`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
"{destination:(?!.*-from-).+}" worked ! You made my day, thank you very much!
("{destination:(?!.*-from-)[^\/]+}" did not)
As a reward, here is a strip about you haha:
http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/02/24/coder-on-the-verge-of-extinction/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
"/route/to-{destination:(?!.*-from-).+}.html"
```

The `^` anchor would search for the start of the string and will fail any match here.

The `(?!.*-from-)` negative lookahead will fail any input that contains `-from-` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

The `.+` pattern will consume all 1 or more chars other than line break chars to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

try using this :->

{destination:^(?!from)+}

or

{destination:^((?!-from-).)+}

Comment: Tried both but didn't worked!
"{destination:(?!.*-from-).+}.html" from Wiktor Stribiżew worked though so there is our solution!
Thanks for helping!