# Spring RequestMapping Regex to exclude string

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

**Background**:
I'm trying to create a backend for a 'Single Page App' web client, that routes all requests to the index.html entrypoint except for anything under `/assets/`.  "/" is mapped to /index.html in a ResourceHandler, and works fine.

**Problem**:
I want to match all paths that do not start with '/assets/' with the RequestMapping in Spring.  This works if I positively match 'assets', but not if I negatively match 'assets' in the regex.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(value="/**")
public class SPARouter {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/{path:(?!assets)}/**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String router() {
        return "forward:/";
    }

}
```

The above code does not work as it never matches any URL. 
If I replace `"/{path:(?!assets)}/**"` with `"/{path:assets}/**"` it will match a URL like `/assets/...`

So the thing that does not work is the negative lookahead / match in the regex.

Is it possible to negatively match a pattern in this way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003857/spring-requestmapping-not-contains-regex Check that

Comment: That nailed it - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I’m not too sure about the negative matching part…

But for your concrete problem (forwarding to `/` for everything except something), the solution I have successfully used is an interceptor. The interceptor checks on the URL, forwards if necessary and, well, doesn’t if not.

Comment: Thanks for the interceptor hint - I was originally looking for the spring boot way of interfering with the request pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^` in mapping as below

`@RequestMapping(value = {"/{path:^(?!assets)}/**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.  One of the many variations of the regex I've tried.